# Property does not exist on type when declaring interface within React Context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am creating an app that will need to set a state outside of a component but read the current state from another. I am using react context for my solution in addition to Typscript but struggling to navigate my Type Errors.

Here is my code:

I am declaring  my interface in my main component as follows:

```
interface ErrProvider {
    LocalName?: string,
}


interface formContextType {

   LocalErrValue: { localErr: Array<any>, setLocalErr: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Array<any>>> }
    errValue: { errors: Array<ErrProvider>, setErrors: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Array<ErrProvider>>> }

}
```

Here is the initialisation:

```
export const formContext = createContext<formContextType>({

    errValue: {
        errors: [], setErrors: () => {

        }
    },
    LocalErrValue: {
        localErr: [], setLocalErr: () => {
        }
    },

});
```

Here is the App

```
export const MyApp = () => {

    const [localErr, setLocalErr] = useState(Array<any>);
    const LocalErrValue = {localErr, setLocalErr}


    const [errors, setErrors] = useState(Array<ErrProvider>);
    const errValue = {errors, setErrors}

    function submitCheck(): void {
         setErrors(localErr)
    } 

return (
    <formContext.Provider value={{ifaErrValue, errValue}}>
     <LocalErrors/
        <button        
            onClick={submitForm}
        >
            <p>Make Reservation</p>
        </button>
    </formContext.Provider>
   )
};
```

As you can see above I wish to set the local errors to my global state when the button is clicked.

interface LocalFormFields {
LocalName?: string
}

export LocalErrors = () => {

```
const {LocalErrValue, errValue} = useContext(formContext);

const {localErr, setLocaErr} = ifaErrValue
const {errors, setErrors} = errValue

const [localForm, setLocalForm] = useState<IFAFormFields>({});

function setField(field: string, value: string | number) {
    // set member of form state
    setlocalForm({
        ...localForm,
        [field]: value,
    });

}

function validateForm(): any {

    const newErrors: any = {};

    if (!localForm.AdvisorName || loccalForm.AdvisorName === "")
        newErrors.AdvisorName = `Please enter first name`;

    return newErrors;
}

useEffect(() => {
    setLocalErr(validateForm())
}, [localForm]);

 return  <div>
           <Form.Group
             controlId="formBasicEmail"
                >
             <Form.Control
              type="name"                               
              placeholder="Local Name"
               onChange={(e) =>
                setField(" LocalName", e.target.value)
                }
                />
                </Form.Group>
               <p>
               {errors.LocalName}
               </p>
             </div>
```

As you can see above, I want to validate the the form from the local component and then set those local Errors to an global error state.

Thee problem is the typescript error that I incur when trying to display from this global error state:

```
TS2339: Property 'LocalName' does not exist on type 'ErrProvider[]'.
```

I am providing LocalName in the interface here:

```
interface ErrProvider {
    LocalName?: string,
}
```

Why does this now throw a TypeScript Error?

Answer (score 0):

Your array of ErrProvider does not have the property LocalName, only individual ErrProviders do. If you want to access the LocalName of each ErrProvider in the array, you could map over them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).